# How can I return null from a function which should return an integer

Tags: c#

I was asked in an interview how to return Null from a method with integer, double type, etc, without any output parameter.

Comment: You don't.  Unless you change the return type to `int?` (which is the same as `Nullable<int>`)  Consuming code would then needs to handle it differently, since the return type has changed.

Comment: Non-local return? (cough) throw an exception (cough)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can do something like this.

You have to make `int` type nullable first. by using `int?` 
normally the `int` datatype in c# are not nullable by default so you have to explicitly convert the `int //not nullable` type to `int? //nullable`

You can do the same thing with double etc..

```
// the return-type is int?. So you can return 'null' value from it.
public static int? method() 
{
   return null;
}
```

You can also write the above method in this way:

```
// this is another way to convert "non-nullable int" to "nullable int".
public static Nullable<int> method()
{
   return null;
}
```

Comment: `Try it yourself.` ?

Comment: I thought you wanted to post a link to eg. dotnetfiddle, but forgot about the link or so.

Comment: anyone else here who was trying to click on `Try it yourself`?

Comment: Sorry...i write that but now i delete it...because it was a bit confusing ithink.☺️

Answer (score 0):

If the purpose is to return null value from a function whose return type is int then you can do something like this:

```
public static int method()
{
    Nullable<int> i = null;

    if (!i.HasValue)
        throw new NullReferenceException();
    else
        return 0;
}

public static void Main()
{
    int? i = null;
    try
    {
        i = method();
    }
    catch (NullReferenceException ex)
    {
        i = null;
    }
    finally 
    {
        // null value stored in the i variable will be available
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You would have to declare your return type as a nullable int. That way you can return an Int or null. See example below:

```
private int? AddNumbers(int? First, int? Second)
{
   return First + Second;
}
```

Comment: How about `private int? GetNull(){   return null;}`